# What should a BindModel() implementation do?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder

I've been reading the [MVC 3 source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) trying to understand what semantics I should adhere to if I override DefaultModelBinder.BindModel() or even implement IModelBinder.BindModel().

It's unclear to me what "state" BindModel() should leave other objects in once it's done with its work.  Sure it's suppose to return a value representing some interpretation of ValueProvider data, but what side effects is it supposed to have?  For example:

- Does MVC have expectations about state of the bindingContext passed to BindModel() *after* the method has finished?
- What, if anything, should IModelBinder.BindModel() set in ModelMetadata?  (DefaultModelBinder sets property metadata in its BindProperty() method, called by BindModel().)
- Should an override of DefaultModelBinder.BindModel() call ModelState.AddModelError(), or is a BindProperty() override a more appropriate place (especially if I want to take advantage of DefaultModelBinder's default behaviors as much as possible)?

DefaultModelBinder has so many semantics built into its plumbing that it makes overriding anything it feel *very* dangerous (i.e. I feel like I can't override anything without violating the [Liskov principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).  Lack of documentation doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom binding I would implement the IModelBinder interface and do what's necessary to build your object.